# Do I use the "and also" in this sentence correctly?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I wrote a sentence:

> There is interesting daily life in the streets and alleys, and also unique places such as old or coloured houses and attractions between streets.

But a senior colleague rewrote it:

> On the streets and alleys, we see interesting daily life and unique buildings such as the old or coloured houses, attractions between the streets.

The main difference between these two sentences is the usage of "and also". So I'd like to know if I used this phrase incorrectly or unnaturally?

Comment: The two versions say different things. Your original quote talks about “interesting daily life” in various places: streets, alleys, old/coloured houses and attractions (eg cinemas). Your colleague’s version talks about sights on “streets and alleys”: interesting daily life, buildings and attractions.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! You might find a lot of valuable questions in [the English Language Learner Stack Exchage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) to help you in the future.

Comment: This is a lot to pack into a single sentence, and some dodgy coordination in both the original and the rewrite. I'd use say << One can easily find examples of interesting daily life in the streets and alleys. There are attractions between streets, and also unique locations such as old and colourful houses.>>

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the original sentence is that it's elliptical—but with an incorrect subject-verb agreement.

When we form an elliptical sentence, we assume that the first part is implied in subsequent parts.

For example:

> **There is** interesting daily life in the streets and alleys, and also [**there is**] unique **places** such as old or coloured houses and attractions between streets.

Since the sentence starts with *there is*, leaving it out of the second part implies that it should be silently repeated (or assumed), in the second part—except that doing so would not be correct in this case.

In order to correct the problem, be explicit rather than using ellipsis:

> **There is** interesting daily life in the streets and alleys, and **there are** also unique places such as old or coloured houses and attractions between streets.

---

That corrects the problem with the grammar. Whether or not the sentence should be rewritten in general or not is something else. It seems that your colleague didn't make the simple correction needed—but decided to make more significant changes. That's more a matter of opinion on their part.

Comment: Now I completely understand. Many thanks for your help .:D